# Past perfect and simple past

Tags: tense

I think these sentences are most idiomatic in the sense that these show the specified time sequence by using past perfect.

> 1. Until you called me, I had been studying for about 3 hours.
> 2. Before you called me, I'd visited a store and bought some foods

But how about these?

> 3. Until you called me, I was studying for about 3 hours.
> 4. Before you called me, I visited a store and bought some foods

I remember seeing this kind of sentences before so I think these are also possible.

Q. In this situation can we use whichever we want to? which one would you prefer to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the **past perfect** to talk about an event which happened before another event in the past.

*I wasn't hungry because I had already eaten much.*

Notice that with regular verbs the past simple and the past participle form of the past perfect is the same.

*It crashed.* *It had crashed.*

However, with irregular verbs the past simple and the past participle from are often different.

*I saw Peter.* *He'd already seen me.*

---

Now, number 2 fits here.
Also, be careful, number 1 uses the **past perfect continuous.**

---

We use the past perfect continuous:

1. to show the cause of something in the past. 
   **His hands were dirty. He had been gardening.**
2. with actions verbs and *for* or *since* to say how long an action had been in progress.
   **I'd been playing the lottery for years before I won anything.**

Answer (score 1):

My intuition as a native speaker is that 1 is preferable to 3 and 4 is as good as 2. Number 3 uses two past tense verbs, even though the initial clause has a very clear cue that past perfect is required: the word *until*.

But what about number 4 versus number 2?

Two things seem to make simple past natural here. The first is the presence of *before* rather *until*. The first refers to some event at any previous time, possibly disconnected from receiving the phone call. With *until*, though, the event, action or state is presented as continuing until the moment of the phone call, which means that the perfect is required.

Consider:

> *Before I met you for lunch, I did not get a croissant from the corner bakery.*

No problem here.

> *Until meeting you for lunch, I had not gotten a croissant from the corner bakery.*

Clearly we cannot replace this with the simple past.

> *Until meeting you for lunch, I did not get a croissant from the corner bakery.*

But when *before* fills the same role as until, it plays by the same rules:

> *Before meeting you for lunch, I had not gotten a croissant from the corner bakery.*

Now that *before* refers to an ongoing state that continues until the present, we must use the past perfect.

We see here that most people would probably use number 4 to refer to a single event, and number 2 to refer to a past situation, that of having visited a store in the past. To convince yourself of this, switch it around, add another verb, and expand the contraction: *I had visited a store and bought some food before you met me.* This seems to refer to someone who is being accused of not knowing how to shop, does it not?

However, these are not hard-and-fast rules. Number 2 might still work if the consequences of the visit were viewed as continuing into the present.